# Creating process and getting error no more files

Tags: c++

I am trying to create process with CreateProcess function and even if the process was created with GetLastError() I am getting 18 error which is ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES. I would like to know how could i fix it.

Code:

```
BOOL WINAPI Procces;

STARTUPINFO si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

Procces = CreateProcess(
"C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe",
"-l D:\\Testing.txt",
NULL,
NULL,
FALSE,
0,
NULL,
NULL,
&si,
&pi);

WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, 1000);

CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
```

Comment: You should not check the error code returned by `GetLastError` unless the previous system call actually failed.

Comment: So how should I check if that process started successfuly?

Comment: If [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) returns `FALSE` you check the error code from `GetLastError`.